# Bokeh error: Model 'Panel' does not exist

Tags: python, bokeh

In a Jupyter notebook with `bokeh` version 0.12.7, I have 3 cells of code as follows

**Cell 1**

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.models import CategoricalColorMapper
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, gridplot
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs

df = pd.read_csv('Data/female_literacy_fertility.csv', thousands=',')
```

**Cell 2**

```
source1 = ColumnDataSource(df[df['Continent']=='ASI'])
p1 = figure(x_axis_label='fertility (children per woman)', y_axis_label='female literacy (% population)')
p1.circle('fertility', 'female literacy', source=source1)

source2 = ColumnDataSource(df[df['Continent']=='EUR'])
p2 = figure(x_axis_label='fertility (children per woman)', y_axis_label='female literacy (% population)')
p2.circle('fertility', 'female literacy', source=source2)

source3 = ColumnDataSource(df[df['Continent']=='AF'])
p3 = figure(x_axis_label='fertility (children per woman)', y_axis_label='female literacy (% population)')
p3.circle('fertility', 'female literacy', source=source3)

source4 = ColumnDataSource(df[df['Continent']=='LAT'])
p4 = figure(x_axis_label='fertility (children per woman)', y_axis_label='female literacy (% population)')
p4.circle('fertility', 'female literacy', source=source4)

row1 = [p1, p2]
row2 = [p3, p4]
layout1 = gridplot([row1, row2])
output_file('bokeh1.html')
show(layout1)
```

**Cell 3**

```
tab1 = Panel(child=p1, title='Latin America')
tab2 = Panel(child=p2, title='Africa')
tab3 = Panel(child=p3, title='Asia')
tab4 = Panel(child=p4, title='Europe')

layout2 = Tabs(tabs=[tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4])
output_file('bokeh2.html')
show(layout2)
```

When I ran the cells in order 1, 2, 3, everything was fine. But if ran cell 2 again (that is 1, 2, 3, 2),  I got this error message

> Bokeh Error
>   Model 'Panel' does not exist. This could be due to a widget or a custom model not being registered before first usage.

The only way to overcome the problem was to restart the kernel again. Does anyone know what the issue was, and how to fix it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Bokeh 0.12.7 is ancient, many issues have been fixed since then so it is impossible to speculate. If you can reproduce on current versions, a Github issue would be appropriate (with full details).

Comment: Thanks for you input, @bigreddot. I tried to update bokeh with `conda update  bokeh` but it didn't work. I then removed the package and reinstalled it `conda install -c bokeh bokeh` but  got this error message `[WinError 126] The specified module could not be found`. I googled it for a workaround but to no avail. Do you happen to have any idea of this new issue?